# C Programming. How to pass string in struct array

Tags: c, string, scanf

Your time and energy is most appreciated

> /* In the space provided below write a C program that asks the user to
> enter the  address and the price of a dozen for-sale residential
> properties in Santa  Monica and stores them by their address, price,
> and type (i.e., condo,  single-family home, or land) in an array of
> structures.  It then prints the  information for those properties
> which are under 1 million dollars. Then using  the embed icon shown
> above, insert screenshots demoing the execution of your code.
> */

Please advise. ie when I type in the address 1439 Cedar Ave, it takes **Cedar Ave** as seperate prompts, when its actually the address and a part of the first prompt.

````
#include <string.h>

//gotta make the structure first:
//declare properties as struct (short for structure) so that 
//the address, type and price all go under properties
struct property {
    char address[100];
    char type[100];
    double price;
};

int main() {
int n,i;//declare i
struct property p[2];
//ask how many properties to add, this'll determine the amount of iterations
    printf("Enter how many properties you want to add: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

//save previous input in &n and iterates/asks that many times about property info
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
    //name + address
    printf("Property #%d\n",i + 1);
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf("%s", &p[i].address); //input goes into structure
    printf("\n");
    //property type
    printf("Enter type: \n");
    scanf("%s", &p[i].type); //input goes into structure
    printf("\n");
    //price
    printf("Enter price: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &p[i].price); //input goes into structure
    printf("\n");
    //makes a space to seperate different properties
    printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\nResidential properties in Santa Monica for sale under $1M: \n");
    printf("\n");

    //this for loop filters out the properties by price
    //excludes properties worth MORE than $1M
    //prints rest of properties UNDER $1M
    
    for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        if (p[i].price < 1000000) {
            printf("Property %d:\n", i + 1);
            printf("Address: %s\n", p[i].address);
            printf("Type: %s\n", p[i].type);
            printf("Price: %lf\n", p[i].price);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: `%s` only reads one word (as you have found). Use `fgets` to get the whole line. Don't forget to remove the trailing newline character if you don't want to store that.

Comment: What happens if the user enters a value larger than `2` for `n`?